# Problems with text/csv Content-Encoding = UTF-8 in Ruby Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

When attempting to load a page which is a CSV that has encoding of UTF-8, using Mechanize V2.5.1, I used the following code:

```
a.content_encoding_hooks << lambda{|httpagent, uri, response, body_io|
 response['Content-Encoding'] = 'none' if response['Content-Encoding'].to_s == 'UTF-8'
}
p4 = a.get(redirect_url, nil, ['accept-encoding' => 'UTF-8'])
```

but I find that the content encoding hook is not being called and I get the following error and traceback:

```
/Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:787:in 'response_content_encoding': unsupported content-encoding: UTF-8 (Mechanize::Error)
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:274:in 'fetch'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:949:in 'response_redirect'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:299:in 'fetch'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:949:in 'response_redirect'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:299:in 'fetch'
    from /Users/jackrg/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize.rb:407:in 'get'
    from prototype/test1.rb:307:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone have an idea why the content hook code is not firing and why I am getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I find that the content encoding hook is not being called

What makes you think that?

The error message references this code:

```
  def response_content_encoding response, body_io
    ...
    ...

    out_io = case response['Content-Encoding']
             when nil, 'none', '7bit', "" then
               body_io
             when 'deflate' then
               content_encoding_inflate body_io
             when 'gzip', 'x-gzip' then
               content_encoding_gunzip body_io
             else
               raise Mechanize::Error,
                 "unsupported content-encoding: #{response['Content-Encoding']}"
```

So mechanize only recognizes the *content encodings*: '7bit', 'deflate', 'gzip', or 'x-gzip'.

From the HTTP/1.1 spec:

> 4.11 Content-Encoding
>
> The Content-Encoding entity-header field is used as a modifier to the
>   media-type. When present, its value indicates what additional content
>   codings have been applied to the entity-body, and thus what decoding
>   mechanisms must be applied in order to obtain the media-type
>   referenced by the Content-Type header field. Content-Encoding is
>   primarily used to allow a document to be compressed without losing the
>   identity of its underlying media type.
>
> ```
>    Content-Encoding  = "Content-Encoding" ":" 1#content-coding
> ```
>
> Content codings are defined in section 3.5. An example of its use is
>
> ```
>    Content-Encoding: gzip
> ```
>
> The content-coding is a characteristic of the entity identified by the
>   Request-URI. Typically, the entity-body is stored with this encoding
>   and is only decoded before rendering or analogous usage. However, a
>   non-transparent proxy MAY modify the content-coding if the new coding
>   is known to be acceptable to the recipient, unless the "no-transform"
>   cache-control directive is present in the message.
>
> ...
>   ...
>
> 3.5 Content Codings
>
> Content coding values indicate an encoding transformation that has
>   been or can be applied to an entity. **Content codings are primarily
>   used to allow a document to be compressed** or otherwise usefully
>   transformed without losing the identity of its underlying media type
>   and without loss of information. Frequently, the entity is stored in
>   coded form, transmitted directly, and only decoded by the recipient.
>
> ```
>    content-coding   = token
> ```
>
> All content-coding values are case-insensitive. HTTP/1.1 uses
>   content-coding values in the Accept-Encoding (section 14.3) and
>   Content-Encoding (section 14.11) header fields. Although the value
>   describes the content-coding, what is more important is that it
>   indicates what decoding mechanism will be required to remove the
>   encoding.
>
> The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) acts as a registry for
>   content-coding value tokens. **Initially, the registry contains the
>   following tokens**:
>
> **gzip** An encoding format produced by the file compression program "gzip" (GNU zip) as described in RFC 1952 [25]. This format is a
>   Lempel-Ziv coding (LZ77) with a 32 bit CRC.
>
> **compress**  The encoding format produced by the common UNIX file compression program "compress". This format is an adaptive
>   Lempel-Ziv-Welch coding (LZW).
>
> ```
>     Use of program names for the identification of encoding formats
>     is not desirable and is discouraged for future encodings. Their
>     use here is representative of historical practice, not good
>     design. For compatibility with previous implementations of HTTP,
>     applications SHOULD consider "x-gzip" and "x-compress" to be
>     equivalent to "gzip" and "compress" respectively.
> ```
>
> **deflate**  The "zlib" format defined in RFC 1950 [31] in combination with the "deflate" compression mechanism described in RFC 1951 [29].
>
> **identity**  The default (identity) encoding; the use of no transformation whatsoever. This content-coding is used only in the
>   Accept- Encoding header, and SHOULD NOT be used in the
>   Content-Encoding header.
>   http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.5

In other words, an http *content encoding* has nothing to do with ascii v. utf-8 v. latin-1.

In addition the source code for Mechanize::HTTP::Agent has this in it:

```
  # A list of hooks to call after retrieving a response.  Hooks are called with
  # the agent and the response returned.
  attr_reader :post_connect_hooks

  # A list of hooks to call before making a request.  Hooks are called with
  # the agent and the request to be performed.
  attr_reader :pre_connect_hooks

  # A list of hooks to call to handle the content-encoding of a request.
  attr_reader :content_encoding_hooks
```

So it doesn't even look like you are calling the right hook.

Here is an example I got to work:

```
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new

p a.content_encoding_hooks

func = lambda do |a, uri, resp, body_io| 
  puts body_io.read
  puts "The Content-Encoding is: #{resp['Content-Encoding']}"

  if resp['Content-Encoding'].to_s == 'UTF-8'
    resp['Content-Encoding'] = 'none'
  end

  puts "The Content-Encoding is now: #{resp['Content-Encoding']}"
end

a.content_encoding_hooks << func

a.get(
  'http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/myprog.rb',
  [],
  nil,
  "Accept-Encoding" => 'gzip, deflate'  #This is what Firefox always uses
)
```

myprog.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'cgi'

cgi = CGI.new('html3')

headers = {
  "type" => 'text/html',
  "Content-Encoding" => "UTF-8",
}

cgi.out(headers) do
  cgi.html() do
    cgi.head{ cgi.title{"Content-Encoding Test"} } +
    cgi.body() do
      cgi.div(){ "The Accept-Encoding was: #{cgi.accept_encoding}" }
    end
  end
end

--output:--
[]
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"><HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Content-Encoding Test</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><DIV>The Accept-Encoding was: gzip, deflate</DIV></BODY></HTML>
The Content-Encoding is: UTF-8
The Content-Encoding is now: none
```

Comment: thanks for your extensive response. I know it didn't call my hook because I added a breakpoint in the code and it didn't break.  The goal of my code (I believe, since I copied it from xxx) was to catch a content-encoding of "UTF-8" and turn it into 'none' so that the code you showed would not kick the response out. As far as the spec is concerned, that may be great but the website is returning content-encoding = 'UTF-8', so your observation that that is inappropriate is accurate though irrelevant.  Continued -->

Comment: Finally, are you saying that the content_encoding_hooks is the wrong hook to call and that I should be using the post_connect_hooks? I admit that I found an example (https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/issues/138) and just followed it.

Comment: Well...if you are trying to intercept the response before mechanize processes it and throws that error, and your hook does not succeed in doing that...then it would be worth trying another hook.

Comment: Okay, I looked at the source code more carefully, and you have the right hook. I posted an example that I got to work, but I can't duplicate your error. Note that in mechanize 2.7, the headers are the 4th argument for get()--not the 3rd. I don't know if that has changed since mechanize 2.5. When I use your code to call get(), I get a different error. Also, you should probably use a legal value for the Accept-Encoding. The legal values are the same as for Content-Encoding.